# How to remove a repo that isn't in /etc/apt/sources.list?

Tags: apt, repository, software-sources

I want to remove a repo (from `packages.cloud.google.com`) but it isn't in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. (I haven't reproduced that file because the output is very long, but honestly, it isn't in it) But it does appear in the output of `sudo apt update` and it is listed when I run `apt policy`:

```
t0p@pluto:~$ apt policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now

<snipped for length>

 500 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main i386 Packages
     release o=cloud-sdk,a=cloud-sdk,n=cloud-sdk,l=cloud-sdk,c=main,b=i386
     origin packages.cloud.google.com
 500 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main amd64 Packages
     release o=cloud-sdk,a=cloud-sdk,n=cloud-sdk,l=cloud-sdk,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.cloud.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages

<snip>
```

The only way I know to remove a repo is to delete its entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. But this one isn't in that file, so I'm at a loss.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to remove the repo from my system?

Comment: Have you looked in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory?

Comment: In `terminal` do `grep -i packages.cloud.google.com /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` and you'll find it.

Comment: t0p@pluto:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ grep -i packages.cloud.google.com /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
t0p@pluto:~$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
t0p@pluto:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
<snip>
google-cloud-sdk.list
<snip>
t0p@pluto:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ cat google-cloud-sdk.list
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main